# How to reverse Latex 2021-06-01 Update? => kvoptions error

Tags: kvoptions

I am working with my university's template and everything was just working fine, till I updated all Packages in MiKTeX automatically. Just after this update I get this warning (I have never had this before the update...)

```
Package kvoptions-patch Warning: kvoptions-patch is not compatible
with LaTeX 2021-06-01 Loading is aborted on input line ....
```

So my Question is, how can I reverse the recent update? or how can I reverse the Update for the `kvoptions` package?

Comment: it doesn't error. It only warns you. Probably you can ignore the warning. Or try to find who is loading it, and look if you can remove the package. Normally it is not needed.

Comment: If I complile the file, I get various Errors and actually they are changing from time to time. So I think they are influenced by the kvoptions warning? How can I ignore the warning?

Comment: If you get errors show the errors. And make a small but complete example that demonstrates them so that we can test.

Comment: It's complicated. My university's template is loading \RequirePackage{kvoptions} with the class "prelimitaries". Since the update I get the kvoptions warning + mutliple errors of formatting e.g.:
- "Unknown float option `H'. \begin{figure}[H]"
- "Dimension too large. \preliminaries"
So I guess since the update, kv-options doesn't work anymore with my template...

Comment: your logic is quite flawed. You made an update which changed many things, and only because one of them issues a warning you assume it is responsable for your errors. kvoptions is *not* the source for an unknown float option error. Add \usepackage{float} to avoid it. And it also is not the  source of a dimension too large error. Stop to believe that there is an easy way out by reverting kvoptions and start to handle the errors properly.

Comment: Well the thing is, that actually if I click on the kvoptions warning, while it its compiling I get no error... the compiling finishes, I get my document but in the document there are formatting errors....

Comment: well if you are convinced that kvoptions is the culprit then make a small, complete example and open a bug report at https://github.com/ho-tex/kvoptions. Then I will investigate the issue.  If this is too difficult for you, go to the maintainer of your template and tell them that it no longer compiles in a current tex system and ask them to correct it (or to open a bug report in an appropriate place if they think there is a bug).

Comment: ok thanks, i appreciate that. i am a latex beginner, so i believe you that my problem can have any reason.